# How much current can a computer power supply deliver when used as differential power supply?

Tags: power-supply, current, high-current

I have a computer PSU which has +12 and -12 volt rails. Although on the side of the supply it says that the -12V line can only deliver 0.5 A, I have tried connecting the +12 and -12 lines across a 5 ohm resistance in order to get 24 volts across it, and when I measured the current it said 4.6 A. Why does this work? How safe would it be to use this method to get 1.5 A at 24 volts for longer time intervals?

Comment: The -12V can only SOURCE 0.5A, it can probably sink far more, as you've seen.

Comment: Well, that's my question. Is it MADE to be able to sink more than 0.5 amps? Can I reliably use it to sink 1.5 amps? Then why can't I find anyone on the internet who did a 24 V supply from a PSU? I can only find people who made 12 V supply's.

Comment: @KyranF  If it were an answer, I would -1 it for being adverse advice.  Possibly, the negative supply has some capacity to work in overload.  That would explain the 4.6A, which was observed by Calin.  But how long can such overload last?  What failure mode to expect if it's overloaded too long?  Only the designers of the PSU would know.  I would not deem it safe to use a 0.5A supply at 1.5A for any extended period of time.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I wouldn't deem to safe to use a split supply for 24V shenanigans at all. Sounds like black magic to me. Especially if the end circuitry interfaces with anything else grounded

Comment: @Calin are you telling me you cannot find a 24V supply? the most common industrial power supply DC voltage out there? Check this out http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/desktop-power-supply/0188781/

Comment: Use a 2 amp boost module on the 12v rail to get the 24v you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends greatly on the exact power supply model, but in general I would not use it unless you example the schematics of your PSU.

Example 1: http://www.smpspowersupply.com/ATX_power_supply_schematic.pdf

In this schematics, +12V and -12V actually come from the same winding on the transformer.
The only difference is -12V has PR1507 diode rated 1.5A, while +12V has U20C20 high speed, dual diode rated 20 amperes.
So if your PSU looks like this, you can get +24V as long as you make sure the diodes do not overheat (it is quite possible that -12V diode has no proper heatsink, and thus it cannot handle full 1.5A for extended periods of time)

Example 2: http://www.smpspowersupply.com/atx-power-supply.html

In this schematics, -12V comes from a separate transformer using 7912 regulator. If you try to draw too much current, either L4 will not be able to provide it, so the voltage will sag, or 7912 will overheat. D5 will then start conduting and your -12V line will measure around +0.7 volts. If your PSU looks like this, you should not try to get +24V from it.